# Robocopy errors when running Jenkins script

Tags: robocopy, jenkins

I've tried to follow other SU links [Getting robocopy to return a proper exit code](https://superuser.com/questions/280425/getting-robocopy-to-return-a-proper-exit-code)

and I've have this step in Jenkins

`(robocopy d:\vol\CruiseControl.NET\Websitecode\%SITENAME%" "\\%SERVERNAME%\websites\_builds\%SITENAME%" /mir) ^& exit 0`

I'm still getting errors and its supposed to ignore the exit code. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You have a single quotation mark on the source at the end. Put another quotation mark at the start of the `d:\...` section and try again

Comment: That worked. Sorry been staring at it too long

Comment: @user238546 Don't be afraid of marking it as an answer